# How to increment properly

Tags: java, increment

i have an issue with my code where i can only increment the last input data value, this code it linked to another class where i have song list etc. however im tryin to create a playlist where when i press play it increments the playcount of all the songs in the playlist. however my problem is once i add the songs to a playlist, when i press play it only increments the last track in entered into the text field. for example i type "01" then add then i type "02" and add, but it only increments track 2 (hence the last track i added) instead of incrementing both 1 and 2. im very new to java so forgive me if this seems trivial, and thanks in advance.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == add) {
        String key = trackNo.getText();
        String name = LibraryData.getName(key);
        if (name == null) {
            playcount.setText("No such track number");
        } else {
            playcount.append("\n" + name + " - " + LibraryData.getArtist(key));

        }
    }
     if (e.getSource() == reset) {
            playcount.setText("");
    }
     if (e.getSource() == play) {
         String key = trackNo.getText(); 
         LibraryData.incrementPlayCount(key);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Don't compare strings like `name` with `==`.

Comment: the main problem with the code (i think) is from if (e.getSource() == play) onwards, the rest of the code works how i want (sort of).